# Dns errors in the domain

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, dns-zone

The Domain name is: www.intralifeindia.com

I updated all records. when i checked up DNS details using http://dnscheck.pingdom.com i found an error as :

```
Too few IPv4 name servers (1).

Only one IPv4 name server was found for the zone. You should always have at least two IPv4 name servers for a zone to be able to handle transient connectivity problems.
```

Already two name servers are added as i checked that.

Then SOA ERROR SAYS:

```
SOA MNAME for intralifeindia.com (ns1.secureserver.net) is not authoritative.

The name server listed as the original or primary source of data for this zone does not answer authoriative. This is probably due to a misconfiguration - perhaps the SOA MNAME is not set up as name server for the zone.

Delivery over IPv4 to info@s192-169-188-190.secureserver.net could not be done.


Failed to deliver email for SOA RNAME of intralifeindia.com (info.s192-169-188-190.secureserver.net) using info@s192-169-188-190.secureserver.net.

DNSCheck failed to deliver email to the email address listed as the one responsible for the zone.
```

I went to domain details i can not change SOA primary name server. It is : Primary NameServer   info432270.mars.orderbox-dns.com

Answer (score 4):

You have the same IP address for both `ns1.intralifeindia.com` and `ns2.intralifeindia.com`. This is not allowed, you need to have two separate nameservers on different servers for your domain.

Also, the contact e-mail address listed in your `SOA` record (info@s192-169-188-190.secureserver.net) is not working.

Comment: i have site running up but dns errors are displayed.
I have dedicated server for this. i don't understand why such DNS errors are shown. anything to fix?

Comment: You need to get two separate name servers for your domain. Your hosting provider should be able to help with this. If not, then I recommend you hire a proper professional to set it up.

Comment: As for why multiple servers are needed, refer to the [related Q&A](http://serverfault.com/questions/710108/why-is-geo-redundant-dns-necessary-for-small-sites) and [BCP 16](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp16#section-3.1).