# Failed to resolve host: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4

I have set up a DNS server using BIND on CentOS 7. By checking the DNS server in [BuddyNS](http://www.buddyns.com/delegation-lab/amraei.com) and using `dig amraei.com` it seems good and working.

Then I have also setup Apache and a virtual host for another domain `involv.ir`. Now the domain `involv.ir` is not accessible and replying to `ping`. If I try to trace it, I get this error:

```
:~$ mtr involv.ir
Failed to resolve host: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

While tracing DNS server using `mtr amraei.com` shows it's working properly.

How to troubleshoot this problem and check if it is DNS or Apache related?

Comment: It's already telling you it's DNS related.

Comment: @yoonix I could probably guess that is a DNS related problem, but what's the problem? How to solve it? Can I do something more than setting DNS for my domain?

Comment: You are using a single nameserver IP. Please review [Why is geo-redundant DNS necessary for small sites?](http://serverfault.com/questions/710108/why-is-geo-redundant-dns-necessary-for-small-sites). This may not be the only problem, but you need to start there. The problems exposed by the linked Q&A are one of the many reasons why ["Should we host our own nameservers?"](http://serverfault.com/questions/23744/should-we-host-our-own-nameservers) is usually a good question to ask ourselves.

Comment: @AndrewB I have tested this approach before and it was working just with one IP. In most cases when I even have used a DNS hosting service they just has provided one IP. If you check `ns1.kassit.com` and `ns2.kassit.com` (which belong to me) they also have one IP and are working properly.

Comment: The linked Q&A refers to the appropriate section of BCP 16. The fact that this is a volatile DNS configuration at the mercy of routing burps is not an opinion - it is a well-established fact. If you are sure that this is not the problem for different reasons (i.e. you are experiencing this problem without traversing the internet, or it happens for longer than 5 minutes at a time), there is not enough information here for us to provide assistance. I suggest analyzing the traffic with `tcpdump`.

Comment: @AndrewB I think there is misunderstanding here. If you point to amraei.com in your browser you can see both DNS server and Apache are working properly. The problem occured when I have used nameservers for another domain `involv.ir`.  Some errors here: http://www.intodns.com/involv.ir

Comment: (edited out the contents of this comment, OP was likely tweaking the zone as we were troubleshooting it)

Comment: @Sven You were right. I created a zone for involv.ir and problem just solved. Why you deleted your comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you asked this question, there where no nameservers defined for `involv.ir`. According to `intodns.com` and your comment, this is now fixed.

Without NS records, nothing else can work.

You should fix the other issues reported by `intodns`, at the very least the ones in red.