# Website monitoring frequently reporting 'dns resolution failed' on azure cloud service

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, website

Disclaimer: You'll usually find me on SO but not sure there is right place for this question!

I have an Azure cloud service website monitored by NewRelic which will send me alerts when it's unable to ping the host (among other tasks).  I've recently being getting a lot of `Unable to ping` alerts and the site cannot be resolved, when looking at the detail it states 'DNS resolution failed`.

Now I understand the alert, but unsure why it's appearing so frequently and if there's anything I can do about it (my instincts are telling me no)?

Also, is this something related to Azure or could it even be that there is a problem with the app which is taking the site down and this is the net result of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An error *"DNS resolution failed"* means that your site and app can't even be found and reached. If your site name can't be resolved in DNS wether or not your site and app are up and running or not becomes a moot point, visitors can't reach them regardless.

If it is appearing frequently there is something wrong with the authoritative name servers and you might want to change them. [This Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/710108/37681) gives some background to why it is important to have reliable authoritative name servers.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought.  Do you have any other information you could provide on how I might go about changing the authoritative name servers?

Comment: From where-ever you currently registrar your domain. Many of the large cloud hosting providers also offer DNS hosting, allowing you to control everything from the same API which might give you some other benefits as well.