# how to point my domain name to VPS server

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, a-record

I have domain name registered with crazydomains.com  and linux vps server with godaddy. I want to point my domain name to VPS server Ip address. so question is

1. Do i need to setup DNS server using BIND in my VPS ?
                       or
2. Add A record in a crazydomains panel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option number two is your only task.

Comment: Agreed. #1 is a [frequent misunderstanding](http://serverfault.com/questions/23744/should-we-host-our-own-nameservers) and [a very bad idea](http://serverfault.com/questions/710108/why-is-geo-redundant-dns-necessary-for-small-sites).