# DNS Verification using TXT not working

Tags: domain-name-system, website, verification

I have followed the instructions for setting the TXT record for chemicalkinetics.info (registered through siteground).

After waiting several days, I still cannot get verification. 
My only guess has to do with information I saw with whois, namely:

Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited

Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited

Does verification involved 'transfer'? Is this the problem (if this is the case, how do I rectify it -- preferable through my provider, siteground)?

Comment: Setting DNS records (on the registered Name Servers for your domain: NS1.CLEV14.COM & NS2.CLEV14.COM ) has nothing to do with domain transfer protection (used to prevent/allow switching domain registrars).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your domain does not exist as far as DNS on the internet is concerned. These are your nameservers:

```
chemicalkinetics.info.  86400   IN      NS      ns1.clev14.com.
chemicalkinetics.info.  86400   IN      NS      ns2.clev14.com.
;; Received 85 bytes from 199.249.121.1#53(b2.info.afilias-nst.org) in 14 ms

;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

As demonstrated above, those nameservers are not reachable by clients on the internet. Further testing shows that those DNS servers do not even respond to external requests for the domain they are associated with (`clev14.com`):

```
$ dig +trace +additional ns1.clev14.com A

; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P2-RedHat-9.7.0-21.P2.el5_11.6 <<>> +trace +additional ns1.clev14.com A
;; global options: +cmd

[snip]

clev14.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns1.clev14.com.
clev14.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns2.clev14.com.
ns1.clev14.com.         172800  IN      A       184.154.227.2
ns2.clev14.com.         172800  IN      A       184.154.227.102
;; Received 96 bytes from 192.48.79.30#53(j.gtld-servers.net) in 97 ms

;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Let's review:

- These IPs do not respond to requests for `clev14.com`.
- These IPs do not respond for `chemicalkinetics.info`.

Even if these DNS servers did respond, they [ignore BCP 16](https://serverfault.com/questions/710108/why-is-geo-redundant-dns-necessary-for-small-sites) and both live in the same /24. It is doubtful that the operator is sufficiently trained to run those servers. If your company is attempting to run its own authoritative DNS infrastructure, [this is generally considered a bad idea](https://serverfault.com/questions/23744/should-we-host-our-own-nameservers).

Comment: Thank you for your comments.... the DNS server seems to be the problem.. I am rectifying the problem through siteground now. I think the question can be considered answered.

Comment: Final update: Correcting the DNS server solved the problem. Problem solved. Thank you all for your help in resolving this issue

Answer (score 3):

I think chemicalkinetics.info should exists before being able to add any record for it. Can you see it?

```
host -t soa chemicalkinetics.info google-public-dns-a.google.com
Using domain server:
Name: google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases:

Host chemicalkinetics.info not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

or

```
host -t any chemicalkinetics.info google-public-dns-a.google.com
Using domain server:
Name: google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases:

Host chemicalkinetics.info not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood something...

Comment: chemicalkinetics.info domain name is registered to me (from Siteground).

Comment: You can do a whois to see this... However, it is not hosted (associated with a distinct IP)... Is this necessary to verify it with google? In any case, how can I fix this (or what are the requirments) to get verified?

Comment: @EdwardBlurock This is a failure of Siteground. They will have to fix whatever the problem is.